# Explanation and fix for Possible null pointer dereference of

Tags: java, findbugs, pmd

Code review tool is complaining *Possible null pointer dereference of safeScanWarnings in saveSafeScan(...)* At the line *if (safeScanWarnings != Null & safeScanWarnings.size() > 0)*

I am wondering how is this possible? Is this because we are returning the collection by reference?

```
protected void saveSafeScan(final Response response, final Dtec dtec) throws dtecException
    {
        Collection<String> safeScanWarnings = dtec.getSafeScanWarnings();
        if (safeScanWarnings!=null && safeScanWarnings.size()>0)
        {
            Iterator<String> iterator = safeScanWarnings.iterator();

            int i = 0;
            while (iterator.hasNext())
            {
                String safeScanCode = iterator.next();
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    response.setSafeScanCode(safeScanCode);
                    response.setSafeScanCodeText(getMessage(String.format("DTECRESPONSE_SAFESCANCODE_%s",
                            StringUtils.trimToEmpty(safeScanCode))));
                }
                SafeScanWarning safeScan = new SafeScanWarning();
                safeScan.setCode(safeScanCode);
                safeScan.setMessage(String.format("DTECRESPONSE_SAFESCANCODE_%s", StringUtils.trimToEmpty(safeScanCode)));
                safeScan.setPriority(i);
                response.getSafeScanWarnings().add(safeScan);
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: While in your example the code is correct in your error the if has a `&` and no `&&`. So make sure that in the real code it's the shortcircuit evaluation. If that's already the case it's a bug in the tool.

Comment: notice your comment above the code sample is  `if (safeScanWarnings != null & safeScanWarnings.size() > 0)`  which is wrong (buggy)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If it's really pointing to that line, it looks like a bug in the code review tool to me.

As it's a local variable, there's no chance that it'll be changed by anything else between the nullity check and the `size()` call - so there's no way it'll throw a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

There is a branch of statement that, if executed, guarantees that a `null` value will be dereferenced, which would generate a `NullPointerException` when the code is executed. Of course, the problem might be that the branch or statement is infeasible and that the `NullPointerException` cannot ever be thrown. Deciding that is beyond the ability of `FindBugs`.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute "dtec" should be securised:

```
    if (null!=dtec && null!=safeScanWarnings && safeScanWarnings.size()>0)
    {
      Collection<String> safeScanWarnings = dtec.getSafeScanWarnings();
```